# Why is a PPM6 file smaller than a PPM3 file?

Tags: image, graphics, ppm, image-formats

Maybe it's a weird question but I'm little confused why PPM6 is smaller than PPM3.
According to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format), in PPM3, each pixel is represented as 3 bytes

```
P3
# The P3 means colors are in ASCII, then 3 columns and 2 rows,
# then 255 for max color, then RGB triplets
3 2
255
255   0   0     0 255   0     0   0 255
255 255   0   255 255 255     0   0   0
```

further they say that P6 binary format of the same image represents each color component of each pixel with one byte (thus **THREE bytes per pixel**). The file is smaller but the color information is not readable by humans.

I don't understand why P6 is smaller if in both cases each pixel is represented with 3 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse your source data with what actually gets written to a file.

PPM3 is not represented by 3 bytes per pixel. Well, not in the stored form. You store them as text files. 3 digits (255 for example) stored as text is 3 bytes (a byte per character). Not 1. And I'm not even regarding the white space there.

PPM6 is stored as binary with indeed 3 bytes per pixel. It will therefore always be smaller.